# dynamodb scan with delay (or limited provision) - nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

So i am just starting and learning dynamodb and encountered the following problem,

I am using [connect-dynamodb](https://github.com/ca98am79/connect-dynamodb) to implement a session database with dynamodb, and while developing and learning at the same time i learned that scans are expensive, however - connect-dynamo (as any db framework) uses a reap interval to clean expired sessions, and scans the table every X interval.

i found a nice solution [here](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx3VAYQIZ3Q0ZVW/Rate-Limited-Scans-in-Amazon-DynamoDB), but this is using a java class - and was wondering if there is any similar parallel solution with nodejs.

if not, would be glad to hear about any other good solution for a infrequently schedule read burst. like a scan with "delay" to avoid exceeding read capacity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using node and dynamoDB allot and just looked inside the module connect-dynamo.

The main problem with this modul is that it uses a table of type "HASH".
It should be a "RANGE" table with `expires` as range key.
Then it is possible to do a query instead of a scan, wtich is way cheaper.

So my advice is not to use this module ;-)

Or fork it and change it to RANGE table!

Comment: you have to specify hash when you query. and the hash is uuid.

Comment: That's right, but the Module itself creates a dynamo-hash table. In it would create a range table it would be possible to get the outdated sessions by "query" instead by a "scan". So that would be much cheaper. So in my opinion it is a design error of the session module "connect-dynamo"

Comment: If i find some time tomorrow in the train and have a usable Internet-Connection i will try to implement a pull-request for the module ;-)

Comment: say i want to query all session that are older then a year. so how would you do that? query(expires > year && hash==???), what will be the hash of the range table? sorry if i am missing a basic thing.